# How can I keep the following asynchronous pattern DRY in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The basic pattern is if X do something asynchronously else do something synchronously.  For example

```
if (varNotSet) {
    setVarAsynchronously(function(callback) {
        // process callback then...
        render(page, {'var': myVar});
    });
}
else
    render(page, {'var': myVar});
```

What's bothering me is the following

```
render(page, {var: myVar});
```

since the same code is repeated.  Is there some way that I can encapsulate that logic in a single place?

Comment: `render(page, {var: myVar});` => `render(page, {'var': myVar});` or else ERRORS

Comment: I'm not sure whats going on in that second line of code. Its like your calling a function called `setVarAsynchronously` and then I don't know why there is a body. That's not a function definition is it? Is that supposed to be a callback that you pass to `setVarAsynchronously`?

Comment: Sorry I was rushing I have fixed things up

Comment: If you are using jQuery, the deferreds and promises (and also the whole ajax interface using them) makes this really easy and simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, I highly recommend its build-in $.Deferred function which is available sincs version 1.5
It is made precisely to help with issues like the one you wrote.

Using jQuery, you would do this the following way:

```
var def = new $.Deferred;
var promise = def.promise();
if (varNotSet) {
    setVarAsynchronously(function(callback) {
        def.resolve();
    });
}
else
    def.resolve();

promise.done(function () {
    render(page, {'var': myVar});
});
```

If the deferred object's promise was already resolved, its callback is run immediately, otherwise it runs when it is resolved. Later you can attach more callbacks to the promise with .done(), and all of them will be called immediately if the deferred object was resolved.
(You don't have to make a promise object from the deferred object for making callbacks, it is just an optional thing that allows you to separate setting the deferred's status from being able to add callback listeners. Otherwise you can do everything on the deferred object.

Comment: Deferred objects are nice for this kind of situation. It should be noted that there are also dedicated deferred object libraries, so it does not have to be jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use another function.

```
function resolve() {
    render(page, {'var': myVar});
}

if (varNotSet) {
    setVarAsynchronously(result) {
        // process result then...
        resolve();
    }
}
else resolve();
```

Answer (score 0):

The completely generic way of doing this could be a helper function like this:

```
// helper function
function runWhenVal(val, asynchFn, fn) {
    if (!val) {
        asynchFn(function(callback) {
            fn();
        });
    } else {
        fn();
    }
}

// using the helper function
runWhenVal(x, setVarAsychronously, function() {
    render(page, {'var': myVar});
});
```